# How cloudflare caches dynamic pages?

Tags: django, caching, cloudflare

I have a django application and I would like to enable cloudflare to speedup the web response.So I would like to know how much cloudflare can caches my application? 
In the application most of the pages are dynamic and eachone atleast contain the loggedin user name.Is there any other way cloudflare handle highly cacheable websites

Answer (score 3):

CloudFlare's CDN caches the following types of static content by extension for all account types by default:

```
css,bmp,tif,ttf,docx,js,pict,tiff,eot,xlsx,jpg,csv,eps,woff,xls,jpeg,doc,ejs,otf,pptx,gif,pdf,swf,svg,ps,ico,pls,midi,svgz,class,png,ppt,mid,webp,jar
```

From this [page](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172516-Which-file-extensions-does-CloudFlare-cache-for-static-content-), it is said that:

> If you are looking for more advanced caching or performance options,
>   please look at our paid plans that can help extend caching and
>   performance for your site.

Also, the about Cloudflare's caching mechanism, its explained in this [page](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/205177068-Step-1-How-does-CloudFlare-work-):

> To speed up the response time for a request that goes to a one of our
>   frontline servers, CloudFlare caches parts of websites that are static
>   in these servers. For example, we cache things like images, CSS, and
>   JavaScript. We are very conservative with our caching because we never
>   want to mess up dynamic content. So, for example, as a general rule we
>   do not cache HTML. We also refresh the cache relatively frequently, so
>   files are never more than a few hours old. Even being conservative,
>   however, typically 50% of the resources on any given web page are
>   cacheable.

And about the point about `eachone atleast contain the loggedin user name.`. Its related to django backend. I have used a django powered site with cloudflare, had no problem with logged in users.

You can check this library for caching: https://github.com/koalalorenzo/django-smartcc

Answer (score -1):

Try a page rule like this as your last one:

*example.com/*

There should be an asterisk at the beginning and end of this rule

Choose "cache everything."  This will cache html.

Test results on your dynamic content caching.